# Can I use polymerisation glue for acryl in aquarium water?

Tags: aquarium, safety, freshwater, poison

I created a protection for my filter entry with acryl and polymerisation glue [Evonic Acrifix 1R 0192](http://www.acrifix.com/product/acrifix/us/products/reactive-cements/acrifix-1r0192/Pages/default.aspx) in form of a cube. Can I use it in my aquarium (under water) without harming fish after drying it completely with UV light and leaving it outside 1 day?

I figured that covering the edges with aquarium silicone wouldn't help, since it would only cover blunt edges and eventually toxic parts of the glue could emerge from sharp edges.

I have a 60 l freshwater aquarium with mollys and wels catfishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can safely use the glue you mention. UV activated glue does not give off toxins after it is fully cured.

The link you provide is dead, so here is [a new one](https://corporate.evonik.com/en/media/press_releases/new-adhesive-for-ultimate-bond-102032.html). I have no connections to the company and this link is only posted for information about the product.

Another type of glue you can use is cyanoacrylate; you can read more about it [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyanoacrylate). On the middle of the page you can read about its use in aquariums.

After cyanoacrylate is fully cured, it is safe for your fish; cyanoacrylate is the same as superglue.

Personally, I prefer to use aquarium silicone if the tank is made of glass, as this handles movements of the glass better, resulting in lower possibility of the glass breaking during use.